# How to get the Node's server IP behind a load balancer in Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, load-balancing

I have a webpage behind a load balancer, and I want to display the user (for troubleshooting purposes) the IP of the actual node that the user is connected to (will be the same for a while due to sticky session)

I'm sure it's a very trivial question, but I want to be sure, what Java API should be used for that? will all APIs return me the request host? or will it be server dependent?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901755/how-to-get-the-ip-of-the-computer-on-linux-through-java wherein multiple interfaces are considered.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can any one suggest me some API for python to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` will give you the name of the server you are on.
`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` will give the IP Address of the server you are on.