# Get all ipaddress of a linux machine

Tags: java, networking

How to get all IP adresses of a Linux machine using Java?

My device has two IP adresses, but while trying to get all IP addresses by using the below, it will return only a primary IP address. The same piece of code works fine for Windows.

```
InetAddress myAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("myaddr::::" + myAddr.getHostName());
InetAddress localAddress[] = InetAddress.getAllByName(myAddr.getHostName());
int len = localAddress.length;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
  String localaddress = localAddress[i].getHostAddress().trim();
  System.out.println("localaddress::::" + localaddress);
}
```

Comment: Look at [How to get the ip of the computer on linux through Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901755/how-to-get-the-ip-of-the-computer-on-linux-through-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should take a look on NetworkInterfaces class of Java.
You'll query for all available interfaces and enumerate over them to get the details (ip address in your case ) assigned to each one of there.

You can find example and explanations [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can get

```
 InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
 NetworkInterface neti = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
 byte macadd[] = neti.getHardwareAddress();
 System.out.println(macadd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ListNets {

public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
     System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
     Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
        displayInterfaceInformation(netint);     
}

static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
    out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
    out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
    for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {

        out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
    }
    out.printf("\n");
 }
}
```